# What do these particles mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, verbs

Could you tell me what the following sentences mean?

(1) I **outed** fast. And you say he’s – what is he?
(2) But one of the daughters was sleeping in with Mum at night – but she’s **upped** and **offed**.

Is "she's" in (2) a shortened form of "She was"?

Comment: Are they from the same context? Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are examples from this book:
 [Google Books "The English Phrasal Verb"](https://tinyurl.com/ycqjxqlo)

They are examples of some phrasal verbs where the greatest part of the meaning is carried by the particle. The evidence the book offers for that is a couple of references from literature where the verb itself has been dropped, and the particle is used as if it were a verb.
The phrasal verbs in question are "got out", for the first example, and "got up", and "taken off" for the second example. The actual verbs "get" and "take" are omitted, and "outed", "upped", and "offed" are used instead.

So, example 1 means "I got out fast."

In example 2, the contraction "she's" is actually "she has", so the meaning is
"she has gotten up and taken off" = she arose and left.

Answer (score 1):

**Outed** is generally used to mean that someone's homosexuality has been revealed by a third party.

People also talk about gays **coming out** (of the closet) when they declare their own sexuality.

**She's** is an abbreviated form of **she has**. She has got up and gone off - in a hurry.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outed